# Error with a NSLocalizedString with parameter

Tags: objective-c, ios, parameters, nslocalizedstring

I have to print a localized string passing it a parameter.

I use:

```
 NSString *myMsg = [[NSString alloc] 
   stringByAppendingFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"MyKey", @""), aString];
 [MyViewController updateMyMessage:myMsg];
 [myMsg release];
```

In the Localizable.strings, I use:
"MyKey" = "My message says: %@";

**EDIT:**

It works, using this code:

```
NSString *myMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(@"MyKey", @""), aString];
 [MyViewController updateMyMessage:myMsg];
```

However, I would to know what's the problem in the the former code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fran,

stringByAppendingFormat appends to an existing string. Since myMsg has not been initialized the first example doesn't work.

You can reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html and make sure you are using a method for creating or initializing strings.

Hope that helps,

Ryan